# Can I pass CSS selectors as props in react to style classes within an external component?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have imported a markdown editor (quill) and want to style specific classes of it.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="text-editor">
        <ReactQuill
          value={this.state.text}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          modules={this.modules}
          formats={this.formats}
          placeholder={'this is lappen'}
          style={{  }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I can pass style attributes to quill. But I'd like to only style specific classes within the component. Can I do that by passing the styling as props somehow?

I want to do the following:

```
.ql-container.ql-snow {
  border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: You can pass the className or style object, but if you pass like that how that will be executed?

Comment: it does not work if i just pass it

Comment: Why are you passing selectors along with styles ? You can directly apply style to the component, with the style passed as props

Comment: I just wanted to ask if there is a way to do that? Otherwise, I need to create a separate file only for this little block.

Comment: No, you can't send in styles this way. As the styles applied in the components will be inline styles. And inline styles will not allow selector specific styling. But you can pass in the style and that style can be applied to the component. Example passing styling https://codesandbox.io/embed/wonderful-dijkstra-3483x?file=/src/App.js